# Edit HTML in text edit field in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, html-editor

I have a text string with *basic* HTML tags like `<b> <i> <ul> <ol>` tags.

Now I want to display it **parsed** in a **editable** text box and allow user to edit in a WYSIWYG way. How can I do it in C#?

Right now I have a `RichTextBox` but it uses RTF tags under the hood not HTML, so instead of formated text I see html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is using a `WebBrowser` control, showing editable div:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
    <div contenteditable=""true"">
        This is a sample:
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li><b>test</b></li>
            <li><a href=""https://stackoverflow.com"">stackoverflow</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ div >";
}
```

You can also have some toolbar buttons for setting text bold, italic, or insert `<ul>` or `ol` and other commands. For example, the following command, makes the selection bold:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Bold", false, null);
```

Or the following command inserts ordered list:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("InsertOrderedList", false, null);
```

You may also want to take a look at following post:

#### [Windows Forms HTML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59119227/3110834)

[image: Windows Forms HTML Editor]

Comment: Thanks a lot. First item on your list is what I was looking for